# How to get User ID from Token

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm creating something and I want it so that when you type `!token <token>`, it will find the name and avatar that belong's to that token.

Problem: I cannot run another bot and I get this dum error:

```
handle: <Handle <TaskStepMethWrapper object at 0x7f8e24068220>()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 81, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeError: Cannot enter into task <ClientEventTask state=pending event=on_message coro=<bound method BotBase.on_message of <discord.ext.commands.bot.Bot object at 0x7f8e30184b50>>> while another task <ClientEventTask state=pending event=on_message coro=<bound method BotBase.on_message of <discord.ext.commands.bot.Bot object at 0x7f8e30184b50>>> is being executed.
Exception in callback <TaskStepMethWrapper object at 0x7f8e24068d90>()
handle: <Handle <TaskStepMethWrapper object at 0x7f8e24068d90>()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 81, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeError: Cannot enter into task <ClientEventTask state=pending event=on_message coro=<bound method BotBase.on_message of <discord.ext.commands.bot.Bot object at 0x7f8e26333b50>>> while another task <ClientEventTask state=pending event=on_message coro=<bound method BotBase.on_message of <discord.ext.commands.bot.Bot object at 0x7f8e30184b50>>> is being executed.
```

I would completely understand if it isn't possible to get the user id from token and if not if you know how to JUST REMOVE that error that would be nice, code:

```
@client.command():
async def token(ctx, token):
  client2.run(value)
  await client2.wait_until_ready()
  await ctx.send(client.user.id)
  client2.stop()
```

Please note: that is not the original code, I don't want anyone to steal my original code, this works completely the same except without embeds and message edits which I believe don't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can't run 2 bots at once. Second, use !token and share your token with other people is very dangerous. Third, you should never get access to other people's token. It gains you full access to the account.

Comment: first is all i really needed. I have given up on the idea lol. the bot was not gonna use the token in the way shown above (it was an example)